# What wire goes where and controls what on this 2 wire setup?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have a double light switch in my bedroom. The switch on the right controls the ceiling fan/light. It is an on/off switch for the entire fixture. The only way to turn off the light and leave the fan running is by using the pullchain. The switch on the left controls absolutely nothing that I can find. I've tried the various outlets in the room and none of them are affected by this switch. Can anyone figure out what is going on here? Why are the switches hooked up to only two wires? You can see they used red and black. What about all those white wires in the back of the box? I'd like to be able to control the light with one switch and the fan with the other. Is that possible or should I just leave this mess alone? [image]

Comment: Did you check both halves of each duplex receptacle when checking? It's common for only one half of a receptacle to be switched.

Comment: Impossible to guess what the other switch is/was/should be controlling. But *in general* you appear to have black=hot, red=switched hot, white=neutral. If it is consistent then it *may* be that you have black/red/white going from here to the fan/light *and not going on to power other stuff then it should be possible to rewire so that black and red control light and fan separately using a double switch. Also possible (as in @Ecnerwal's answer) that both cables are going to the fan/light and a little rewiring up there will make the two switches work as desired. **Picture of fan wiring please.**

Answer (score 1):

"All the whites in the back" are Neutral wires for the power supply coming in, that power continuing to elsewhere (I think, hard to follow wires clearly in that picture) and the switched power going out to the things the switches control.

Figuring out where the cable connected to the switch that doesn't appear to do anything goes is not particularly possible from this side of a computer screen far away. If it goes to the fan box, and isn't connected usefully there at present, perhaps it can be reconnected to do what you want.

Do you have a picture of the wiring at the fan?